# Efficient hashing of `std::bitset` or `boost::dynamic_bitset<>` for Boost's unordered containers

Tags: c++, hash, bitset, boost-dynamic-bitset, boost-unordered

I'm wondering if there's some efficient way to hash `std::bitset` or `boost::dynamic_bitset<>` for Boost's unordered containers?

I'm currently converting `std::bitset` or `boost::dynamic_bitset<>` to `std::string` first before hashing them, but it seems this is going to be slow.

Is there some better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C++11 requires standard library to have `std::hash<std::bitset>` specialized. IOW it should have hash already.

For boost you should use config: `#define BOOST_DYNAMIC_BITSET_DONT_USE_FRIENDS` then the `dynamic_bitset::m_bits` member becomes public and you can make hash on it.